# plone - webdav - all content uploaded via webdav becomes locked

Tags: webdav, plone

I uploaded a bunch of content via webdav earlier and it appeared in the front-end; however, I must have changed some setting, but now anything new that I upload is locked and does not appear in the front end.  If I unlock it, it appears to be deleted.

Comment: If I disable locks with davfs2, the fuse filesystem, it appears to work.  Still, it is odd though that existing content became locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled locks for my webdav client and that resolved the issue.  Not the greatest solution, but it works.